# How to append a custom HTML attribute or CSS class using a .NET data annotation attribute?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-attributes

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM. Is it possible to change the HTML rendered from a View Model, by using an attribute?

Example:

```
public class Product
{
    [AddHtmlAttribute(Name = "disabled", Value = "disabled")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want the attribute to be able to change the rendered HTML, that property results in. I know it properly can't be done with an attribute alone. I probably have to hook into the system by implementing an interface, but where should I look?

I know MVC uses the default editor templates, and I've looked at them in the MVC 3 source code, but  I haven't been able to figure out if it would be possible to somehow hook into the rendered  element and add some attributes. I know the validation system does this, by adding custom HTML attributes to support unobtrusive validation.

I guess I just need a pointer to where I should look, or what interface I should take a look at.

Thank you so much.

**Update:** I'm using the standard HTML helper `Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)` for my fields, and haven't overriden any editor templates. I would really prefer if I didn't have to change or override the default templates.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your view code? Are you using input helpers, editor templates (built in, custom)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) which illustrates how to achieve this by writing a custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, attribute and overriding the default templates.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's very helpful. However, I was kind of hoping it could be done without overriding the default templates

Comment: @Gunder, nope, I am afraid it can't. If you use EditorFor the default templates are rendered and if you don't override them they won't contain such attributes.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, is the approach in that blog post still applicable in MVC5, or is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: Sadly the blog is no longer there. The link is dead.